# How to print image with title in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need some help with an ongoing project I am stuck in the output of matplotlib where I want to output multiple images, each with a title of a model prediction and of what the output actually is, I am using this code for output:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('CovidClass.h5')
if y_test[446] == 0:
    out = "This patient is not infected"
elif y_test[446] == 1:
    out = "This patient is infected"
    
plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))

plt.subplot(2,3,1) 
img = X_test[446]
plt.imshow(img)
plt.title(print("The prediction for image being infected is:", (model.predict(inpu)*100), "%"),
         print ("Actual label:", out))
plt.axis("off")
```

but it outputs the title as a normal printing statement and the image alone without a title.

Comment: Remove the print functions from the title: use just the text. You'll have to concatenate the various parts together into a single string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the `print` statement, `plt.title()` simply takes a string as input. Also, you can use f-string formatting to make it easier:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
plt.subplot(2,3,1) 
img = X_test[446]
plt.imshow(img)
plt.title(f"The prediction for image being infected is: {model.predict(inpu)*100}%. Actual label: {out}")
plt.axis("off")
```